# Getting error NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

Tags: angular, lambda, deployment, serverless, angular-universal

I'm want to deploy my angular app to AWS lambda but While running `ng add @ng-toolkit/serverless --provider aws` and `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal`
I'm getting **NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID** Kind of error.
My current angular app consists

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/serverless": "^8.1.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: I am getting the same.